# Create SQL Server table with foreign key output in Talend Open Studio 8.x

Tags: sql-server, bigdata, etl, talend

I'm using Talend to migrate one table from one SQL Server (source) to other SQL Server (target).

The source table not have any index. And I want to add some index at target table.

In Talend studio, How I can add or create the index for target table?.

How I do it? Or what Talend's component should I use?.

I am using Talend Open Studio 8.0.1 and SQL Server 2019.

Thank you.

Comment: Seems an awful lot like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71536018/create-sql-server-table-with-foreign-key-output-talend-open-studio-8-x) which you just asked yesterday .... please don't repost the same question over and over again. If it was closed, that's a sign it wasn't clear enough or focused enough - work on your question, make it better - don't just repost it.....

Comment: maybe try to use a tDbRow  component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **tDbRow** component to execute the sql statement and don't forget a **tDbCommit**  component to commit the database and close the connextion if needed

the query you need to execute is as such  **Create Nonclustered Indexes**

```
create nonclustered index indexname on tablename(columnname)
```

**Drop Index**

```
 Drop Index index name on tablename
```

**See all Indexes in a database**

```
 select * from sys.indexes
```